# Wordpress htaccess rewrite rule not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to hit the following url:

```
mysite.com/e-recording-counties/e-recording-in-utah
```

and have the server receive:

```
mysite.com/e-recording-counties/state?state=utah
```

but it looks like it is getting:

```
mysite.com/e-recording-counties/state
```

and the browser location shows:

```
mysite.com/e-recording-counties/state
```

Here is my htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/e-recording-in-(.*)$ ?pagename=$1/state&state=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been struggling with this for far too long. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the QSA flag (query string append)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
RewriteRule ^/e-recording-counties/e-recording-in-([a-z]+)$ /e-recording-counties/state?state=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Edited to add -
The example above would only cover the URL you gave as an example. After looking at your own rewrite rule I think I see what you're after.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/e-recording-in-(.*)$ /index.php?pagename=$1/state&state=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Dave, unfortunately this didn't work. I tried it both with and without the leading forward slashes. It goes to the URL I want (mysite.com/e-recording-counties/e-recording-in-utah), but the server returns a 404, suggesting it never receives the URL with the variable.